# Hibernate, JPA - unidirectional one-to-one

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wanted to implement one-to-one relation using Hibernate and JPA. I have two classes that are part of an hierarchy: Question hierarchy and Answer hierarchy.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class QuestionUnit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private AnswerUnit correctAnswer;
...}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AnswerUnit {

    @Id
    private int id;

    public abstract Object getAnswerContent();

    public abstract boolean isEqual(AnswerUnit otherAnswer);

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and we have OpenQuestion and OpenAnswer as implementations.

I wanted so the table with OpenQuetions would have auto-generated primary key, and the table with OpenAnswer would have primary key that has the same value as the primary key in the OpenQuestion table.

I tried to follow the example from here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html
part 2.2.5.1. One-to-one.

But when I persist the OpenQuestion, I get the table OpenQuestion with columns `id`,`questionContent` and OpenQuestionAnswer with `id`,`answerContent`, but the values of the ids don't match.

So, where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have an "CorrectAnswer" column at "OpenQuestion"? 
 This should be the foreign key to the ID column at "OpenAnswer" - 
i.e - these should be the matching IDs values. 
If you don't have this column - I suspect you have some sort of error in your JPA mapping. 
Edit - to myself - 
Please add MappedSuperClass. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) about it.

Comment: That is the point, as I said, in OpenQuestion I have only `id` and `questionContent`, and everything about the mapping is in the code I think.

Comment: You also need @MappedSupperClass - please see my edited answer. Took me some time to get reminded in it.

Comment: I can't use MappedSuperClass, you can't use mappings to classes that are not annotated with entity, and I have class QuestionList which has ArrayList of QuestionUnits.

Comment: MappedSuperClass is used on super (parent) classes. Your super class is annotated with an Entity.

Comment: Yes, it is mapped as entity because of the reasons I posted in my previous comment (collection of QuestionUnits and mapping).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what are you trying to do, Why are you having a one to one relationship from question to answer?? logic tells me that a question can have many answers (and probably only one correct answer).

And using that approach you shouldn't need to care about the two id's being equal, if thats the case you should have a model like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class QuestionUnit {
    @Id ... private int id;
    @OneToMany private List<AnswerUnit> answers; //optional assuming there's a list of answers for every question
    @ManyToOne private AnswerUnit correctAnswer;

    public void setCorrectAnswer(AnswerUnit answer){
        if(answer.getQuestion().equals(this)){ //or maybe instead answer.setQuestion(this)
            this.correctAnswer = answer;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeError("Answer does not belong to this question");
        }
    }

    //Other getter and setters
    //Override the "equals" method!!!
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AnswerUnit {
    @Id private int id;
    @OneToMany private QuestionUnit question;

    public abstract Object getAnswerContent();    
    public abstract boolean isEqual(AnswerUnit otherAnswer); //should't you just overwrite the equals method in here?    
    //Other getter, setters, etc
}
```

And then to use it, something like this:

```
QuestionUnit q = new OpenQuestion();
List<AnswerUnit> answers = new List<OpenAnswer>();

AnswerUnit a1 = new OpenAnswer();
AnswerUnit a2 = new OpenAnswer();
AnswerUnit a3 = new OpenAnswer();

a1.setQuestion(q);
a2.setQuestion(q);
a3.setQuestion(q);

//Also set the contents and other required info for the questions...

//And then associate the instances:
q.setAnswers(answers);
q.setCorrectAnswer(a3);

em.persist(q);
```

this would work even with open and regular answers

Comment: The question has only one answer because in classes that implement this abstract class, there is a field called question content. The type of this field depends on the type of the question. But all questions share one thing - they have correct answer, and this answer is also some concrete subclass of AnswerUnit concrete class. That is why there is one to one with correct answer.

Comment: But then it would mean that EVERY question can only have ONE answer, and in that case I would advise you to revise your model. Maybe to make the answer an Embedabble entity or even delete that entity and include the answer fields directly in your Question class.